# Unmarshaling split JSON messages

Tags: json, apache-camel, unmarshalling

I'm trying to split up a JSON array, received from a REST call, and unmarshal the JSON into a POJO. Something strange is happening though.

I have JSON like this:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "result": [
        {
            "startTime": "2021-08-12T00:16:00+00:00",
            "time": 1628727360000.0,
            "high": 45790.0,
            "low": 45757.0
        },
        {
            "startTime": "2021-08-12T00:17:00+00:00",
            "time": 1628727420000.0,
            "high": 45805.0,
            "low": 45779.0
        },
        {
            "startTime": "2021-08-12T00:18:00+00:00",
            "time": 1628727480000.0,
            "high": 45810.0,
            "low": 45800.0
        }
}
```

And I'm using a Camel route like this:

```
...
.toD("https://this.that/api/times?start_time=${headers.test}")
.split().jsonpath("$.result").streaming()
.unmarshal(format)
.log("Response: ${body}")
```

But instead of getting getting JSON as a stream, it looks like I get a linked hash map. Here is the error:

```
Error processing exchange. Exchange[BC23BB391A801FE-0000000000000000]. Caused by: [org.apache.camel.InvalidPayloadException - No body available of type: java.io.InputStream but has value: {startTime=2021-08-13T01:32:00+00:00, time=1.62881832E12, open=44769.0, high=44769.0, low=44749.0, close=44749.0, volume=2000.325} of type: java.util.LinkedHashMap on: Message. Caused by: No type converter available to convert from type: java.util.LinkedHashMap to the required type: java.io.InputStream with value {startTime=2021-08-13T01:32:00+00:00, time=1.62881832E12, high=44769.0, low=44749.0}. Exchange[]. Caused by: [org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException - No type converter available to convert from type: java.util.LinkedHashMap to the required type: java.io.InputStream with value {startTime=2021-08-13T01:32:00+00:00, time=1.62881832E12, high=44769.0, low=44749.0}]]
```

I'm trying to follow the Camel documentation. I'm new. It seems like I only need to set streaming to true. I've tried with and without .streaming(). How is this supposed to work?

[Edit]

It looks like the .streaming() doesn't do anything here. Regardless the .split() turns the JSON into a LinkedHashMap, which I can work with, but only because the JSON array I'm splitting is flat -- only one object, nothing nested.

Comment: Try logging the value returned by split and jsonpath before unmarshalling to see if the value returned by jsonpath is valid. Encountered bug(?) in camel-jsonpath not too long go where I tried to get json-objects from json-array that matched a specific condition which occasionally resulted with invalid json (possibly due to no matching entries?).

Comment: I've tried that. The JSON before the split is good and valid. It's where I got the example from.

Comment: Is the json valid after you call jsonpath.

Comment: Hi Pasi. I updated my OP. It looks like after the .split(), the body is a LinkedHashMap, and not JSON anymore. The extra ] is from the error format, I think.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jsonpath and specify that you want it to return result as String, then use marshal using ListJacksonDataFormat and use split after that.

```java
JacksonDataFormat modelListFormat = new ListJacksonDataFormat(SomeModel.class);

//...
.setBody().jsonpath("$.result[*]", String.class)
.unmarshal(modelListFormat)
.split(body())
// do stuff
```

Comment: I guess jsonpath should work and is also scalable in case the response gets modified